# ExtJs ArrayStore (reload or reinit?) is it possible?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have the following Extjs3 ArrayStore.  Elsewhere I'm listening for a value and reloading the store w/ new data elsewhere in the page (the code below the store). I'm looking for a way to 'reset' or reinit the store to it's original data after the load..i.e the next time thru the listener

The Store:

```
  var applicationVersionStoreOriginalData = [
            <c:set var="firstLoop" value="true"/>
            <c:forEach var="productline" items="${environmentLookup.productlines}">
            <c:forEach var="application" items="${productline.applications}">
            <c:if test="${!firstLoop}">,
            </c:if>
            <c:set var="firstLoop" value="false"/>
            ["<c:out value="${application.recid}"/>","<%=ValueC.PRODUCT_NOT_LISTED%>","<%=ValueC.PRODUCT_NOT_LISTED%>"]
            <c:forEach var="applicationversion" items="${application.applicationversions}">,
            ["<c:out value="${application.recid}"/>","<spring:message text="${applicationversion.applicationversion}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>","<c:out value="${applicationversion.recid}"/>"]
            </c:forEach>
            </c:forEach>
            </c:forEach>
        ];

    var applicationversionStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: ['applicationId', {name: 'applicationversionName', type: 'string'}, 'applicationversionId'],
        data: applicationVersionStoreOriginalData,
        originalData: applicationVersionStoreOriginalData
    });
```

The Data load:

```
function filterApplicationVersionStore(appRecId) {
        console.log('AppRecId =' + appRecId);
        var store = Ext.getCmp("applicationversionCombo").getStore();
        var unlistedData = [[appRecId,"-- My version is not listed here --","-- My version is not listed here --"]];
        var applicationVersionStoreOriginalData = Ext.getCmp('applicationVersionStoreOriginalData')
        var applicationVersionCombo = Ext.getCmp('applicationversionCombo');

        if (!store.originalData) {
        store.originalData = store.getRange();
        }

        if (appRecId == '0309CD56B8CF4245A49E8C201C59AD36') {
            console.log('loading new data');
            store.loadData(unlistedData, false);
            store.reload();
        }
        else {
            console.log('loading old data');
            if (store.originalData) {
            store.loadData(store.originalData, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I would now like to be able to reload the store with the data from the original; Is that possible?

MANY MANY THANKS!

I'm in ExtJs3.4

here is what I'm seeing in the console..

```
passing appRecId to function = AAEBD771130144A3A207F8BDF10B910F 
AppRecId =AAEBD771130144A3A207F8BDF10B910F 
loading old data 

---WORKS (if i disable //store.loadData(store.originalData, false);) -- otherwise the store has dupes and seems to contain mulitples

passing appRecId to function = 0309CD56B8CF4245A49E8C201C59AD36 
AppRecId =0309CD56B8CF4245A49E8C201C59AD36 
loading new data 

--NEW 'EMPTY' DATA IS THERE

passing appRecId to function = 987C7D2D6D194E5196F7598DDC624480 
AppRecId =987C7D2D6D194E5196F7598DDC624480 
loading old data 

--EMPTY!
```

Answer (score 1):

Stores do not support restoring replaced data out of the box... But you can easily implement it yourself.

Here's how that could be done with your code:

```
if (some condition) {
    // save original data before losing it
    if (!store.originalData) {
        store.originalData = store.getRange();
    }

    var data = [
        [appRecId,"-- My version is not listed here --","-- My version is not listed here --"]
    ];
    store.loadData(data, false);
    store.reload();
} else {
    // restore original data
    if (store.originalData) {
        store.loadData(store.originalData);
    }
    // else, that's probably still original data
}
```

**Edit**

How to be sure that `originalData` will always exist:

```
var data = [
    <c:set var="firstLoop" value="true"/>
    <c:forEach var="productline" items="${environmentLookup.productlines}">
        <c:forEach var="application" items="${productline.applications}">
            <c:if test="${!firstLoop}">,</c:if>
            <c:set var="firstLoop" value="false"/>
            ["<c:out value="${application.recid}"/>","<%=ValueC.PRODUCT_NOT_LISTED%>","<%=ValueC.PRODUCT_NOT_LISTED%>"]
            <c:forEach var="applicationversion" items="${application.applicationversions}">,
                ["<c:out value="${application.recid}"/>","<spring:message text="${applicationversion.applicationversion}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>","<c:out value="${applicationversion.recid}"/>"]
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
];

var applicationversionStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['applicationId', {name: 'applicationversionName', type: 'string'}, 'applicationversionId'],
    data: data,
    originalData: data
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm on the right track but still missing something.. when I call getRange() initially it appears to be an empty store.. Do I need to call something to ensure it's populated before the getRange()?

Comment: You could save `originalData` in a `load` event listener with `single: true`. But considering how you get your data, the simplest would be to set `originalData` property of the store when you create it. See the example in my edit.

Comment: man i really appreciate your help.. I updated the question with the new code.. but i'm still getting into trouble. Do I need to completely clear the store somehow? loading the new data works fine but I can never seem to restore it to the original state.

Comment: Remove `if (!store.originalData) { store.originalData = store.getRange(); }` in the second part of your code, before the if/else condition. The code in my edit was a replacement for this part, not meant to be used along with it.

Comment: I get this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' on the store.loadData  -- However loading the new data appears fine.. something about that 2nd loadData(oldData) call creates multiples in the store i think -- is there a easy way to log all store values or size?